# display data from database based on drop down selection

Tags: javascript, php, html-select

Pls help me.
I hav a drop down which contain shop A and Shop B.Shop A has value 1 and shop B has value 2.
when select shop A from dropdown  i want to list the data from database as table corresponding to each shop.
This is my html:

```html
<form action="" method="post" name="form2">
  SHOP
  <select name="shop" id="shop" onchange="javascript: form2.submit()">
    <option>Select</option>

    <option value="1" <?php echo isset($_REQUEST["shop"]) && $_REQUEST["shop"] == "1" ? "selected" : "" ?>>ShopA</option>
    <option value="2" <?php echo isset($_REQUEST["shop"]) && $_REQUEST["shop"] == "2" ? "selected" : "" ?>>ShopB</option>
 
  </select>
</form>
```

And this is my js:

```js
$("#shop").change(function(){
    // get the selected user's id
    var id = $(this).find(":selected").val();

    // load it in the userInfo div above
    $("#container").load("table_data.php?id="+id);
});
```

Comment: hey jomal, don't forget to tag your questions under the language(s) in question

Answer (score 0):

Does `table_load.php` return HTML elements? From the JQuery documentation:

*Description*: *Load data from the server and place the returned HTML into the matched element.*

Your PHP script needs to generate HTML elements to be inserted into the container.  Also, you don't really need the selector, this will be sufficient:

```
var id = $(this).val();
```